# Can't change VS Code color theme

Tags: json

I'm trying to change my VS Code color theme but I'm getting an error in the settings.json file.

The error is "Unable to write into user settings. Please open user settings file to correct errors/warnings in it and try again".

This is my settings.json file:

```
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "PowerShell",
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
   
{
    
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
    "[html]": {
      
}
```

Comment: The number of opening `{` and closing `}` do not match ?

Comment: The only red line which indicates an error is in the first ":"

Answer (score 1):

It has to be valid json file. Intellisense works for VS code.
I don't know thy you have this under `terminal.integrated.profiles.windows`
I think it's for used terminals configuration. In config.json use just

```json
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
}
```

Comment: That fixed my problem! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Your settings file is not formatted correctly.
It needs to start with a { and you have no value for the html.

Here is a start (you need values or leave out html).

```
{"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "PowerShell",
 "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
 "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
 "[html]": {}
}
```

Curious, did you do any manual updates? - or perhaps something went wrong when you chose the Dark theme via the VS Code menu.